# How to pick an Image and crop it before upload?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I need to pick an image from photo galley or take new one, and after that crop the image by x*x (like Skype profile image picker for windows phone) and save it. I am developing an universal windows app with c# for windows 10 mobile and desktop.

I need use tools that the OS give me . and before in windows 8 and 8.1 there was [PhotoChooserTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask(v=vs.105).ASPx) for this work but not in UWP windows 10

[image: Skype image picker]

in screen there is a camera button for take new image or choose one of Photos and after pick one of them we can crop it.

[image: Crop Image after pick]

Comment: @kidshaw I know there is some good library for ASP.Net and other platform. and also in windows 8 and 8.1 there was  **PhotoChooserTask** class that handle this work. but for windows universal i cant find a solution that give me access to pick and crop (exactly what Skype profile image do)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847) to let the end user choose a picture :

```
var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
```

And then use XamlCropControl to let him crop the picture

https://xamlcropcontrol.codeplex.com/

Comment: So there is no way to use the cropping tools that photoLibrary let user crop an image ? @danvy

Comment: Also [xamlcropcontrol](https://xamlcropcontrol.codeplex.com/) this project is not for UWP windows 10.